# Word order. Is that two sentences differ?

Tags: grammar, translation

What words order is better:

> This may not be her plan, but then again it might be so.

or

> This may not be her plan, but then it might be so again.

If it helps, I am trying translate this russian phrase:

"Вероятнее всего, хоть она и не планирует, но ситуация возможно, повторится и на этот раз."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, *then again* means *[on the other hand](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/then-again)* and is used to introduce a new or opposing thought, and separating it causes it to lose this meaning.

From [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/then-again):

> used when you have had a new thought that is different from or the opposite of what you have just said:
>
> > I like to travel but, then again, I'm very fond of my home.

Essentially

> This may not be her plan, but then again it might be so.

means

> This may not be her plan, but on the other hand, it might be so.

Whereas

> This may not be her plan, but then it might be so again.

means

> This may not be her plan, but then it might be so, as it has in the past.